# re.compile - phone numbers python

Tags: python

Hello I have a text fife :

```
You can reach them all by phone on 01 5673412.
Their mother can be reached at 01-4567899. Their father's number is
06 34567811.
```

I need to extract all phone numbers containing 01-2345678 or 01 2345678

```
I am using this:
phone = re.compile('\d{2}[\s-]\d{7}')
```

This is the result I am getting:

```
 ['01 5673412', '01-4567899', '06 3456781']
```

But I want this:

```
['01 5673412', '01-4567899']
```

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: I think your regex is only checking to see whether the string starts with two number or not, try to specify that it has to start with `01`

Comment: Your pattern matches all three numbers.  Do you want only numbers that start with `01`?  Or what about the first two makes them desired and what about the third makes it undesired?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your regex is only checking to see whether the string starts with two numbers or not, you should specify that the string has to start with `01`. Try:

```
phone = re.compile('01[\s-]\d{7}')
```

Comment: Thanks man a lot I was so focused at the last numbers that i haven't noticed the 01

Comment: Note: You could also use `\d+` instead of `\d{7}`, provided that you are certain every  instance is properly formatted.